# AngularJS ng-Grid Heading on the left

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I need a grid with the headings down the left side instead of along the top. I'm not committed to ng-Grid, but I like its many options. Hence the attempt to get it working, but I do need to flip it on its side.

Is this possible, and if so how? This is what I have to try and reproduce, but as the year goes on there will be more columns. Yes, I know I could do it with the months down the side, and that would be easier, but why settle for easy eh....

[image: What I need...]

Thanks for the help.

Cliff.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked it out after a lot more Gooogggling and found this which has solved my problem...

[image: The answer....]

Found on a great resource so all credit to Thomas Street

http://thomasstreet.com/blog/legacy/spreadsheet.html